# Where I can check user-define table type in SQL Server 2008 in SSMS? and how can I insert new column into it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I need to add some more columns into my current `user-define table type in SQL Server 2008`

But I didn't see any table type in particular database under `Tables` .

Where exactly I need to check and how can I modify the design of existing `user-define table type in SQL Server 2008`

I'm using `SQL SERVER 2008` and `SSMS`

Where I can find that table in `SSMS` ,

so that I can go and modify table type.

thanks

for previous question answer

Please can any one help to sql `alter type table` syntax `add column` ?
how can I insert any new column ... as ALTER is not working.. it is disable

Comment: `Programmability -> Types -> User Defined Table Types` right click then "Script as drop and create"

Comment: Thanks a ton.. ;) i'm new to Types that's why didn't get it...

Comment: Can any one help to sql alter type table syntax add column ? 
how can I insert any new column ... as `ALTER ` is not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> User-defined types cannot be modified after they are created, because
>   changes could invalidate data in the tables or indexes. To modify a
>   type, you must either drop the type and then re-create it, or issue an
>   ALTER ASSEMBLY statement by using the WITH UNCHECKED DATA clause. For
>   more information, see 
>   [ALTER ASSEMBLY (Transact-SQL).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186711%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
>
> Points to take care while using user defined table type
>
> 1.Default values are not allowed.
>
> 2.Primary key must be a persisted column.
>
> 3.Check constraint can not be done on non persisted computed columns
>
> 4.Non clustered indexes are not allowed.
>
> 5.It can't be altered. You have to drop and recreate it.