# How to see table type in management studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

How to tell SSMS to show table type ? I created table type using the following command ,

```
CREATE TYPE  [dbo].[TVP_OrderTest] as TABLE(...) GO;
```

But cant see any type folder in SSMS.

Comment: What do you mean by table type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267862/where-i-can-check-user-define-table-type-in-sql-server-2008-in-ssms-and-how-can

Answer (score 4):

```
Programmability -> Types -> User Defined Table Types
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew ! I just found that out . +1 anyway.

Comment: Whenever I can't find an object in SSMS, I have learned to to just automatically dig in Programmability.  All sorts of stuff is hiding under it.